# Installing OroCommerce, composer error messages

Tags: php, json, composer-php

As a pre-cursor to my issue, I have very little SSH or comandline experience so may possibly be maiking a glaring mistake but dont realise it..

I'm trying to install OroCommerce on my shared cloud hosting and have been following the instructions within the readme file produced by Oro but when it comes to installing composer I get the following error:

```
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/sites/mydomain.com
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

Fistly the warning regarding CLI... I've read through a post on here regarding the use of `php -cli composer.phar install` but this makes no difference and the error message is the same.

I've read through the composer guide on creating a `composer.json` file but as the file exists in the `orocommerce-application` folder I'm not sure that creating one is the issue here, perhaps more that I've done something wrong preventing composer from accesisng the file?

I've tried moving the composer.json file from it's folder into the domain's root and whilst that does start installation I then get the following error:

```
Warning: Composer should be invoked via the CLI version of PHP, not the cgi-fcgi SAPI
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)               
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <b>phar:///var/sites/mydomain.com/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/Package.php</b> on line <b>109</b><br />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are running `php composer install` in the same directory where you uploaded/cloned OroCommerce code.

And check your hosting provider documentation (or contact their support) on how to run php from command line, most likely you would have to use a different executable file (-cli flag is not what you need).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need to extend the maximum execution time in your php.ini file, for instance :

ini_set('max_execution_time', 360); // 360 seconds for 6 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to do

```
php composer install --prefer-dist
```

This will install all the required/dependent bundles and libraries
then do 
`php app/console oro:install --env=dev --timeout=99999 --debug=true`

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

for development purpose, or

`php app/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=99999 --debug=true`

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

for production/live purpose

NOTE: --timeout will replace your default timeout in php.ini. It worked for me by extending the timeout.